# Why can not caching build files when run "build -mode development" in vue-cli?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

**vue-cli version**: v3.0.0-rc.3

Why is there no hash value(`[chunkhash:8]`) in the file being built by `vue-cli-service build -mode development`?
(This is NOT `vue-cli-service serve`)

If run with no mode option build(default: production), Webpack append chunkhash to file name.

like([/@vue/cli-service/lib/config/prod.js](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/0b42f2f77a89602dfcfa54d3bbf57f7bdd31420a/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/config/prod.js#L8)):

```js
  const filename = getAssetPath(
    options,
    `js/[name]${isLegacyBundle ? `-legacy` : ``}.[chunkhash:8].js`,
    true /* placeAtRootIfRelative */
  )

  webpackConfig
    .mode('production')
    .devtool('source-map')
    .output
      .filename(filename)
      .chunkFilename(filename)
```

But, file name isn't appended chunkhash to file name when run `-mode development`.

like([/@vue/cli-service/lib/config/dev.js](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/0b42f2f77a89602dfcfa54d3bbf57f7bdd31420a/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/config/dev.js#L6)):

```js
  webpackConfig
    .devtool('cheap-module-eval-source-map')
    .output
      .publicPath(options.baseUrl)
```

Is there any reason not to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do these files have random strings for filenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616718/why-do-these-files-have-random-strings-for-filenames)

Comment: What would be the point in versioning files during development? The version / hash / checksum would be constantly changing. You would also have to reload the page each time to pick up the new filenames but without it, Webpack can do hot-reloading of components and scripts